# Create sharepoint survey lists through visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-survey-list

How to create sharepoint survey lists through visual studio?

I am using sharepoint 2013 and visual studio 2013

Comment: Are you trying to do this using xml markup or using code?

Comment: I need it via xml markup. :)

Comment: I guess the easiest way to go is to create survey list on web site then save survey as template and copy content of manifest.xml file to schema.xml file.

Comment: Will copying entire content from manifest.xml to schema.xml file work?

Comment: It appeares to be much harder then i thought. STP file changed from 2010 version. I tried to copy "List" element from stp file but it does not work. Also i tried to take schema xml file from survey standard feature (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\SurveysList\Survey) but it's not working as well :( (not rendering correctly).